# Is the assignment operator inherited or not?

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading

I know that the assignment operator is not inherited by derived classes, instead the compiler will create a default one if it is not redeclared. But I do not understand why the output of the following code snippet is `Base operator=`:

```
#include  <iostream>
using namespace std;


class B {
protected:
    int h;
public:
        B& operator=(const B& ob){
        if (this!=&ob)         {
        h = ob.h;
        cout << "Base operator=\n";
        }
        return *this;
        }
};

class D: public B  {
protected:
    float r;
public:
};


int main() {

    D a, b;

    a = b;

    return 0;
}
```

Doesn't that mean that when calling `a = b` the base `B& operator=(const B& ob`, so isn't it inherited? Where am I wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generated assignment is "all the base assignments, in order of inheritance declaration", so your generated assignment is essentially

```
D& operator=(const D& d)
{
    B::operator=(d);
    return *this;
}
```

If you were to derive from both `B` and `C` - in that order; `class D: B, C` - it would be equivalent to

```
D& operator=(const D& d)
{
    B::operator=(d);
    C::operator=(d);
    return *this;
}
```

That is, the assignment is not inherited, but it's used.

Comment: Bonus if you can justify why you have the `B` assignment above the `C` assignment ;-)

Comment: Here comes the bonus ;-)

Answer (score 1):

With the expression `a = b`, the compiler generated assignment operator for `D` calls the user-defined assignment operator in `B`.

Yes you are correct that assignment operators are not inherited.

Comment: So it is not called directly like it does with a normal functions, it generated a new ```operator=```function ? Like the compiler thought "How can I generate a new function?" and he decides to use the function in the base ?